# How to get the intersected polygon for each feature from another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have two spatial tables, `ponds` and `state_parks`. Both have the column named `geometry` (MySQL type: geometry, SRID: 4326) where it stores the polygons coordinates.

I want to get all the intersection of the ponds (one pond can intersect one or more parks).

```
(ponds table)                        (state parks table)    

ID   POND_REF   GEOMETRY              ID   STATE_PARK  GEOMETRY
---------------------                 -------------------------
1    Jyum        blob                 1    Fuliao         blob
2    Owie        blob                 2    Bedeleuze      blob
3    Karf        blob                 3    Karinai        blob


(result table)

POND_REF   STATE_PARK         
-------------------------------
Jyum       Fuliao
Jyum       Bedeleuze      
Owie       Karinai        
Karf       Karinai
```

Anyone has any hint how to achieve that using MySQL 5.7